# Position, margin, right, float, div under div right: 0

Tags: css

How can you see to http://jsfiddle.net/73wst/

I want Start under Stop, but I don't know how to style it.

My HTML:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="stop">Stop</div>
    <div class="start">Start</div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.start {
    float:right;
    right: 0;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px; 
}
```

Can you help me?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS: Floating a Column under another Floated Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15915100/css-floating-a-column-under-another-floated-column)

Answer (score 1):

```
clear: right;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73wst/1/

The other rules have nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 1):

Updated jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/73wst/3/

```
clear: right;
```

should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

A few things. Your elements are flowing outside of `.main`, so add:

```
.main {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Then simply:

```
.stop {
    float: right;
}

.start {
    float: right;
    clear: right;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/73wst/2/)